# Firebase connection problem in my project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

**Problem :**

My problem is that I absolutely can no longer connect locally to the database on a project. This problem only concerns me since a colleague always manages to do it and the project works well. Here is what I have in the console when I try to login through a form:

[image]

It works great for my colleagues, it's only me where it bugged .. It happened overnight, I didn't install or remove anything at all... I really don't understand.

So, would you know where the problem is coming from? If you are missing anything, please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Try to Connect to Firebase with Vpn

Comment: Hello Hosseinreza, thank you for your answer ! I tried via another network (4G) but it doesn't work ..

Comment: changing connection is different from using vpn , maybe Firebase is inaccessible in your country , so you need to use vpn

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have all firebase configuration correctly and double check security rule at firebase console for read write permission.

This issue occurred due to bad internet connection that's why it try to get from offline.

Comment: Hello Selvakumar Anushan, thank you for your answer ! I tried via another network (4G) but it doesn't work ..

Comment: May be firebase SDK not correctly installed. Try this npm install firebase --save